# In Appengine of GCP, how can we ensure that using Java code in appengine , it doesn't give 500 error when the app engine is getting startup?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, spring-cloud-gcp

The issue is that we wanted our appengine built on springboot java to autoscale when the request load increases without any downtime but the problem is that the appengine server takes more than 60 seconds to startup because of Springboot java & as per the GCP policy ,it starts allowing the api hits on appengine as soon as 60 seconds of spin-up is reached & it doesn't care whether server is completely startup or not. Hence, those api hits starts getting the 500 error. To tackle this issue , we found on one post that we should put "Warmup" in app.yaml:
inbound_services:

- warmup

We tried putting this Warmup in app. yaml. But it doesn't help.
We have tried using flexi app engine & we also tried cloudrunner but we face the same issue...
Can anyone please suggest a  right solution for this....

Comment: What "GCP policy" are you talking about in terms of starting to send requests after 60s?  If there is already an instance running (ie. you are not scaling from zero), appengine will continue to serve requests from the already-running instances, while the new instance(s) start up.  You should only see 500 errors if the incoming requests overload the running instance(s) before the new instance(s) are ready (ie. if requests are waiting longer than the 10s [pending request timeout](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/how-requests-are-handled#quotas_and_limits)).

Answer (score 0):

Please visit the `AppEngine Admin Console` for your application. You will see a Logs link under the Main section on the left side. Click that and view the Server log. That should give you more information on what caused the 500 Error.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/payment-instrument

"While you must provide a payment method for your accounts, the App Engine free tier has not changed and it is not going away."

What you will see:

If you do not have a valid payment method on the project, you will see:
HTTP 500 errors returned when requests are sent to your app
App log entries in your `App Engine` logs that read "Billing disabled. Shutting down instance."

What you need to do:

You will need to add a payment method to your project if you have App Engine apps using the `Java 8, Python 2.7, PHP 5, and Go 1.11` runtimes in the App Engine standard environment.
To add a payment method to your project:
Create a billing account if you do not already have one.
Add your credit card or other payment method as a payment method.
Link your project to the billing account.